# MFC Dialog Size Question

Tags: mfc, dialog

Good day.

from my vc++ project. .rc file.

`IDD_My_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 233, 273
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_EX_STATICEDGE | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "AMEC FA Tool"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1Q`

How to change config a fixed dialog which size to length = 233 and hight = 273 ?

Any help will be appreciated.

BR!
nano

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Your dialog is already defined to be 233, 273 in size.

Answer (score 1):

What is the question here? Dialog sizes are entered in DLU's, a unit to help with dealing with dialog in a resolution-independent way. If your question is how to display a dialog that is always the same size on the screen, regardless of resolution settings, the answer is 'don't', but if you still must, you'll have to fickle with GetDeviceCaps() and calculate physical->logical->device-dependent conversions. See for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226789%28VS.85%29.aspx and search for DLU on this site.

If your question is how to make a dialog that is a certain amount of pixels high and wide regardless of resolution the answer is again 'don't' but if you really must, use GetDialogBaseUnits() and friends to calculate the right size (in pixels) in OnInitDialog().

If you're asking for something else completely, please rephrase your question.